# Fixed and Variable Cost Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

A restaurant has fixed costs that are \$34,000 per month.  Its variable costs average \$1.80 for breakfast and \$3.70 for lunch/dinner.  The average total bill (excluding tax and tip) is \$5 for breakfast and \$9 for lunch/dinner.  The restaurant serves approximately the same number of breakfast, lunch and dinner entrees.

I am asked to :

Find the number of daily meals (breakfast and lunch/dinner) that must be served if the Eastman Family Restaurant wishes to earn a profit before taxes of \$10,000 per month. (Assume 30 days in an average month)

I used the following equation:

$$3.2(x) + 5.3(2x) = 44000$$

Does this yield the correct solution?  The math that the teacher demonstrated was overly complicated.  But I'm afraid at this point that I may be oversimplifying.

Comment: Don't forget to multiply by the 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ denote the daily number of breakfasts, $L$ denote the daily number of lunches, and $D$ denote the number of dinners

We wish to have $$\textrm{revenue} - \textrm{costs} = 10000.$$

In a month, revenue is simply:

$$\textrm{revenue} = 30(5 \cdot B + 9 \cdot L + 9\cdot D).$$

Costs may be written as

$$\textrm{costs} = 34000 + 30(1.8 \cdot B + 3.7 \cdot L + 3.7 \cdot D).$$

This gives us

$$30(5B+9L+9D) - 30(1.8B+3.7L+3.7D) - 34000 = 10000 \\
30\left[ (5-1.8)B + (9-3.7)L + (9-3.7)D\right] = 44000 \\
96B+159L+159D = 44000$$

If the number of breakfasts, lunches, and dinners are assumed to be the same, say some quantity $x$, then we simply write

$$96x+159x+159x = 44000\\
(96+159+159)x = 44000 \\
414x = 44000$$

Solving, we find $x \approx 106.28$, so we assume that the restaurant must sell $107$ of **each** meal, every day, to make the \$10,000 profit.

Let $B=L=D=107$ and we check our work:

$$\textrm{revenue} = 30(5 \cdot 107 + 9 \cdot 107 + 9\cdot 107) = \$73830 \\
\textrm{cost} = 34000+30(1.8 \cdot 107 + 3.7 \cdot 107 + 3.7 \cdot 107) = \$63532 \\
\textrm{profit} = 73830-63532 = \$10298
$$

---

Another way:

\$10,000 in profit divided over 30 days equals \$333.33 profit per day.

To achieve this, we consider $x$ of each meal to be sold each day. The profit from the meal sales can be written as $$(5-1.8)x+(9-3.7)x+(9-3.7)x = 3.2x+5.3x+5.3x = 13.8x$$

Solving, we have $$x = \frac{333.33 }{13.8} \approx 24.15$$

This means that in addition to covering our costs, we have to sell at least $24.15$ of each mean each day.

To cover the \$34,000 in costs, we perform a similar analysis. \$34,000 in fixed costs divided among 30 days gives us fixed costs of \$1133.33 per day. To cover these costs with our profit from meals, we must sell $y$ of each meal, as found by computing

$$y = \frac{1133.33}{13.8} \approx 82.12.$$

Adding this all together, we have the total number of meals as

$$82.12+24.15 \approx 106.27$$

per day.

I recommend that the business owner find a way to cut down on fixed monthly costs. Or raise prices.

Comment: good call - the original equation I had was only half way there (multiplying it by 30 brings it up to your equation). Great write up. Thanks